# WiFi / Range / Distance Sensor

Tags: proximity-sensor, range-detector

I have a driveway which sometimes gets blocked by cars / people who don’t care or can’t read the sign on the driveway doors saying don’t park here driveway in use.

I am trying to see if there are any distance / range / proximity sensors out there that can detect when an item moves into their field of view and stays there for more than say 10 seconds. (I was thinking distance as if distance is reduced from 10ft to say 5ft something would trigger?)
Like a car parking in front of the driveway. Then from there run some IOT IFTT stuff to run alarms or lights flashing on and off etc. I understand PIR movement sensors but obviously these don’t compensate for when an object moves into the field of view but then doesn’t move after. I have a RPi but don’t want to go to that extent. I am wondering if  anyone has any sensor ideas that could do this without significant outlay! Thanks

Comment: What are your constraints in terms of installation and cabling? Can you get it a permanent power source, or do you need it to run on batteries? How would they need to be connected to a network? Ethernet, WiFi, BLE, ZigBee? Is there a specific point/line which is enough to monitor, or do you need a slightly larger angle (and if so, what is that angle)?

Comment: parktronics or similar will be cheapest solution. From my experience the cheap Chinese US sensor like HRS-04 detects human body from 1.2 meters,  for car may be bigger.

Comment: The inductive loop sensor that detects the metal in a car (as used at stoplight/intersections) seems the go-to solution. Can you lay a wire in the driveway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of sensors, the most appropriate would probably be some kind of time-of-flight (ToF) sensor, also called a distance or proximity sensor. Some even call them LIDARs.

It sends a signal and measures how long it takes to come back after having bounced on an obstacle, yielding a distance.

There are many types, using lasers, light, ultrasounds... They have varying characteristics in terms of range, precision, the angle they cover, their power usage, etc.

Just connect one of those sensors to a wireless MCU (probably an ubiquitous ESP32-based board), and monitor the distance. If it drops below the given threshold and remains there long enough, send a message over WiFi. How it will notify you (email, text, app notification, siren, visual alarm...) is up to you.

ToF sensors are active devices (they have to send something to measure the distance), so they draw more power than a PIR sensor which is passive. This means having the device run on battery will be more difficult, so you may have to be creative and only measure every minute for instance. It is possible that combining a PIR sensor (to detect movement using very little power, wake up and start measuring using the ToF sensor) could help. If you do need to run on battery, double check the board’s deep sleep current, many are not optimised at all for that.

Comment: Thanks for this , never heard of the TOF sensors. Will have a look. Have you any recommendations on a sensor / MCU combination - Am not good at soldering or understanding the complexities of circuit boards. Anything with a USB cable I can throw in would help me a great deal! Looks like the pi is the way to go tbh!

Comment: There are probably tons of such sensors with connectors such as a Qwiic/Stemma QT connector (Sparkfun/Adafruit) or a Grove connector (Seeedstudio/M5 Stack) and matching ESP32 boards or devices. Those do not require any soldering, just connect a board and sensor. You’ll need a case for it though.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, for the problem you have defined, PIR sensors are not an ideal choice as they are good at detecting movement but not presence.

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want. In all cases, you will need a computer(maybe a tiny one) to check analyze the data and take actions. This can be a windows or a linux pc, depending on your taste.

Option 1:
Use a Basic IP camera

You could use an IP camera to preriodically grab images to a computer, run some basic check to detect presence of a car. You would have to factor in the ability to manage ambient lighting condition differences. In some cases this could be tricky in all weather/lighting conditions and you would be expected to have certain image processing skills. The benefit from this approach is that you can find a lot of cheap IP cameras that offer good protection in outdoor environments, plus you could eventually use the camera feed for security purposes.

Option 2:
Use a depth camera:
Intel Realsense and a few other chinese brands offer an ability to measure depth inside images. The cameras are usually comnnected to a computer by USB and give a simple way to detect object presence in a specific feild of view. What you can achieve here is a lot, imagine people have attempted to design self driving vehicles using such cameras.

Option 3:
Basic single point lidar:
Another simpler option could be to put lidar sensors(e.g TF mini). The lidar sensors typically communicate over iic or ttl uart, so you would need some protocol conversion to connect it to a network. A downside of these sensors is that they can only offer a single value of distance from obstruction directly in front of the sensor. Depending on your situation you may need multiple of these.

Hope this helps you male a choice.

Comment: Thanks for this will look into the options but yeh looks like the pi is the way to go. Thanks